# how to mysqli num rows simple echo and empty database

Tags: php, echo

The text in echo does not show. Why isn't it displayed?

```
<?php   
while ($liste1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultat8)){
    if(isset($liste1['naissancesID'])){
        echo '<div class="photos" align="center"><img alt="" src="changements/naissances/images/' . $liste1["naissancesPic"] . '" class="deces">
            <span class="caption">' . $liste1["naissancesName"] . '<p class="texte-deces">' . $liste1["naissancesDate"] . '</p></span></div>';
    }else{
        echo "No value in database";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no rows are returned, the `while` loop will end immediately, so you'll never get to the `if` statement. And when you fetch a row successfully, the ID field will always be filled in, so `isset()` will never return `FALSE`.

You should test the number of rows before the loop.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($resultat8) > 0) {
    while ($liste1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultat8)){
        if(isset($liste1['naissancesID'])){
            echo '<div class="photos" align="center"><img alt="" src="changements/naissances/images/' . $liste1["naissancesPic"] . '" class="deces">
                <span class="caption">' . $liste1["naissancesName"] . '<p class="texte-deces">' . $liste1["naissancesDate"] . '</p></span></div>';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "No value in database";
}
```

Comment: Barmar awesome I did not figure it this way but You made it. Thank You so much for Your help. I wish You a great day.. Best Regards